# Jquery dialog box alert updation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with some content inside and as well as several options in that div area. The div and it's options click events will updated with Ajax call. I have two buttons inside this div which have to pop up different alert boxes when some thing goes wrong. One dialog box contains below options.

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: true,
    height: 400,
    width: 150,
    position: 'center',
    title: 'Term Sheet',
    beforeClose: function(event, ui) {
        console.log('Event Fire');
    },
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Submit": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Run": function() {
            Gosomewhere();
        },
        "Create": function() {
            dosomething();
        }
    }
});
```

If i have clicked the first button and chosen the "Submit" option in the open dialog box. Next, if i click the other button which is in the div, it opens the previous dialog box instead of my new plain dialog box written inside that button event as for example,

```
alert("some message");// but here i get the previous dialog box with three buttons and message content as "some message"
```

Is there any that i can try pop up the fresh dialog box with alert in this button event?

Answer (score 0):

First u try to put three different different alert for those button with different  message see the message and you will found what is the problem